# Toast is not shown android robotium test

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I want to test "Add new item" activity in my application. When user fills data incorrectly and then press OK button - the toast (issues list) is displayed. My question is: How can I check that toast is not shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign a `flag` variable where you handle the `onClick` event of your `OK` Button which issues the `Toast`. Set that `flag` to `true`,and then later check, if the `flag` is `false`, the `Toast` was never shown.

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old post but just in case anyone comes across this question, this is the a better way:
solo.waitForText(text); // put here the toast text

Answer (score 1):

```
    //wait up to a second for the toast
    Date date = new Date();
    TextView toast;
    long elapsed;
    do{
        elapsed = new Date().getTime() - date.getTime();
        toast = (TextView)solo.getView(android.R.id.message);
    }while(elapsed<1000&&toast!=null);

    assertEquals(toast.getText().toString(), "Your ticket(s) has been purchased successfully");
```

This is an extension of the answer given by Aleksandr M in case the Toast takes a while to appear. For example, if the toast is the result of a time consuming operation.

Answer (score 0):

this one is works for me

```
TextView toast = (TextView) solo.getView(android.R.id.message);
assertEquals("toast is not showing", toast.getText().toString(), solo.getString(R.string.error_invalid_phone));
```